# Hibernate xml mapping - JOIN on different foreign key column

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using hibernate 3 with XML entity definitions. I want to join some columns of table `person_data` into an entity based on table `employee`. The problem is that the relation is defined on `employee.person_data_id` to `person_data.person_id`.

```xml
<hibernate-mapping package="...">
    <class name="Employee" table="employee">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <property ... />
        <property ... />
        <property ... />

        <join table="person_data">
            <key column="person_id" foreign-key="person_data_id"/>
            <property ... />
        </join>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But the resulting SQL statement contains:

```sql
... FROM employee JOIN person_data ON employee.id = person_data.person_id ...
```

Looks like the key column is used properly but somehow I cannot tell hibernate to use `employee.person_data_id` as a foreign key. I thought that the attribute `foreign-key` is for this purpose but maybe not.

(I know I can solve this problem by using a `many-to-one` relation but then I have to use an entity `'PersonData'` as component of `'Employee'`.)